# Subview have parent's shadow, even with a background

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, ios13

So I just started developing with SwiftUI and I'm running in a small problem. Subviews are also displaying superview's shadow, even if the superview has a background. Does someone know how to fix this?

```
HStack {
    HStack {
        [...]
    }
    .padding(.leading, 12.0)
    .padding(.trailing, 4.0)
    .padding(.vertical, 16.0)
    .background(Color("lightGreen"))
    .cornerRadius(10)
}
.padding(8)
.background(Color.white)
.shadow(color: Color("tabShadow"), radius: 0.0, x: 0.0, y: -0.5)
.shadow(color: Color("tabShadow"), radius: 0.0, x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
```

As stated, the first HStack's shadow shouldn't be replicated into the child one, but it is. Only the first one though. Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certain modifiers, when placed on a stack, are inherited by all their children. For instance, if you have a stack containing a bunch of Text views, you can place one .font() modifier on the stack and they will all be modified.

It appears that .shadow() is one of those modifiers. As to why only one is inherited, I suspect that the designers of SwiftUI don't expect .shadow() to be called more than once on a particular view, and didn't test for that.

If you are just trying to get a colored line across the top and bottom of the view, maybe try something like

```
.background(Color.white)
.background(Color("tabShadow").offset(x: 0, y: -0.5))
.background(Color("tabShadow").offset(x: 0, y: 0.5))
```

Comment: Funny how that's exactly what I was trying to do, thanks too, helps a lot :)

Comment: @doooouG Glad to help! If I've answered your question, do you mind accepting this answer?

Answer (score 9):

Try `.compositingGroup()` it will make traits only effect the parent view.

[See link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/capsule/compositinggroup()/)

```swift
HStack {
    HStack {
        [...]
    }
    .padding(.leading, 12.0)
    .padding(.trailing, 4.0)
    .padding(.vertical, 16.0)
    .background(Color("lightGreen"))
    .cornerRadius(10)
}
.padding(8)
.compositingGroup()
.background(Color.white)
.shadow(color: Color("tabShadow"), radius: 0.0, x: 0.0, y: -0.5)
.shadow(color: Color("tabShadow"), radius: 0.0, x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
```

Comment: This worked, but I needed to move the `.compositingGroup()` after the `.background()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the shadow the be applied to subviews then use the shadow modifier only inside the .background modifier like so:

```
VStack {
 ...       
}.background(Color.white.shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 1, x: 1, y: 1))
```

Comment: is another way without having to be forced to specify a color since i want it to depend based on the theme.

Comment: This is the actual right answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try `overlay` and `background` tricks when you have to make them render in multiple passes. In above case, the overlay will not be affected by the shadow or other effects.

If you think they are `subViews`, actually, they just render after the `superView`. It's a 2D world. So the overlay will be quite independently.

The only problem is just the size of overlay.

The `hidden()` is used here to occupy the position of invisible overlay. It's very cool if you master these layout skills.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            SubContentView().hidden()
        }
        .padding(8)
        .background(Color.white)
        .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 0, x: 0.0, y: -0.5)
        .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 0, x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        
        .overlay(SubContentView())
        
    }
}

struct SubContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("a")
            Text("b")
            Text("c")
            Text("a")
            Text("b")
            Text("c")
        }.padding(.leading, 12.0)
            .padding(.trailing, 4.0)
            .padding(.vertical, 16.0)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also newbie in swiftUI , but I think the problem is related to modifiers order and the fact that they change the View type.

I was able to solve the problem by adding .background(Color.white) and .cornerRadius(2.0) modifiers just before the shadow modifier and that applied the changes in parent (not children) View.

```
struct TestSwiftUIView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(2.0)
        .shadow(radius: 3)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Wrap your main view with some View and setShadow(1) to that view. and setShadow(0) to your main view. it overrides the parents shadow.
Lets say you have:

```
VStack{
    Text("1")
    Text("2")
}
```

and you want to set shadow to this VStack. So, wrap this VStack with another VStack (any View), and setShadow to that stack. Inner shadow overrides outer shadow. Finally your code should be:

```
VStack{
    VStack{
        Text("1")
        Text("2")
    }.shadow(radius: 0)
}
.shadow(radius: 1)
```